# deploy and undeploy multiple artefacts to JBoss using Maven

Tags: maven-2, jboss, hotdeploy

I intended to use JBoss-Maven-Plugin for hotdeployment of jars to JBoss. I have three projects A, B, C that depend on each other so if I want to redeploy A I first have to undeploy C, then B, then redeploy A, then B, then C. Now I'm having a hard time finding a way undeploying the artifacts and then deploying them in reverse order. Might this be out of Maven's scope and I should be using Ant for this task?

Actually it even gets trickier if I have four projects where B and C depend on A and D depends on both B and C - would that always have to result in a double redeployment of D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without more details but with what I know about the [Maven JBoss Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/), the following questions come to mind:

- What are these JARs?
- Where are they located?
- Did you actually try to specify them all as `fileNames` to [hard-deploy](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) and [hard-undeploy](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/undeploy-mojo.html) them?
- Shouldn't you actually bundle them in an EAR?

Comment: Those JARs are own libraries, they are located in the deploy root folder of JBoss (profile). I could have them bundled as an EAR but (during development) I would rather not to be able to redeploy single JARs without having to redeploy the whole EAR.

Comment: @brunognzls Ok... Did you try to list them under `fileNames`? What happens then?

Comment: Thanks Pascal, yes, just tried it. I had missed out that I can specify multiple fileNames to be undeployed. That solved the problem!